# Japanese language in sqlite db

Tags: php, sqlite

I'm trying to create sqlite db with php (zend framework).
I have the next code:

```
$sqlite = Zend_Db::factory("pdo_sqlite", array("dbname" => "sqlite.db"));
$sqlite->query('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS newTable (word TEXT PRIMARY KEY, description TEXT);');
$sqlite->query("INSERT INTO newTable VALUES (\"".$word."\", \"".$description."\");");
```

Everything is fine and I can create db with needed text. But when I try to use Chinese or Japanese text my resulted db read slowly. I tried read it through php, sqliteman (app for edit sqlite), application on Android.

What should I change for obtain the same result as with English, Cyrillic or any other non-hieroglyphic language?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: SQLite always uses Unicode characters; which exactly does not affect the speed.

Answer (score 0):

Question closed. The problem was in very big amount of tables.